# Are there custom UI toolkits for Android?

Tags: android-widget, twitter-bootstrap, android

The options that the standard UI palette, while OK, are not the most exciting.  Before I go down the road of making some custom elements, I was wondering if there exist any UI toolkits for Android that people knew about?  Or are there any theme toolkits (besides the ones included with Android) that make things look better or add more functionality?

I am looking for something like Twitter's Bootstrap for Android.  Or something like jQuery which makes JS better.  Does such a thing or something similar exist for Android?

Comment: i could not find complete free/opensource toolkit library for android but i found that there are too many standalone projects that provides cool widgets. There is very good tricks to find out those applications and their source codes. Type sample in the google play, you will find that there are countless sample applications. Then look description of app, there is most probably a link that points to source code repository. So, you can collect some cool widgets and create your own toolkit. [[https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sample&c=apps]]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are a lot of libraries available. Here are a few:

http://www.droidux.com/ 
http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/ 
https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/simple-section-adapter 
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger 
https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/deselectable-radio-button 
http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ 
https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh 
http://actionbarsherlock.com/ 
http://www.senab.co.uk/portfolio/pull-to-refresh-for-android/ 
https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid 
http://hansel-and-gretel.com/ 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator 
https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow 
http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

Comment: Is there any UI Toolkit or component package that I can subscribe or buy for android?I